# pandas SettingWithCopyWarning only inside function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

With a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    ["2017-01-01 04:45:00", "2017-01-01 04:45:00removeMe"], columns=["col"]
)
```

why do I get a SettingWithCopyWarning here

```
def test_fun(df):
    df = df[~df["col"].str.endswith("removeMe")]
    df.loc[:, "col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col"])
    return df

df = test_fun(df)
```

but not if I run it without the function?

```
df = df[~df["col"].str.endswith("removeMe")]
df.loc[:, "col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col"])
```

And how is my function supposed to look like?

Comment: because inside your function, your `df` is a copy of the global `df`, while outside of the function, you actually modify the global `df`.

Comment: does it still not throw a warning if you do `import warnings` and on the next line

`warnings.simplefilter('always', UserWarning)` and then both the codes? (both should throw warning) , to avoid use: `df[~df["col"].str.endswith("removeMe")].copy()`

Comment: why is it a copy? how I the function supposed to look like?

Comment: @anky_91 I thought i tried that allready... appearently I didn't :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function, you have `df`, which when you index it with your boolean array, gives a view of the outside-scope `df` - then you're trying to additionally index that view, which is why the warning comes in. Without the function, `df` is just a dataframe that's resized with your index instead (it's not a view).

I would write it as this instead either way:

```
df["col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col"], errors='coerce')
return df[~pd.isna(df["col"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Found the trick:

```
def test_fun(df):
    df.loc[:] = df[~df["col"].str.endswith("removeMe")]  <------- I added the `.loc[:]`
    df.loc[:, "col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["col"])
    return df
```

### Don't do `df = ...` in the function.

### Instead do `df.loc[:] = ...` !